# Check a boolean or a string when logging in to parse-platform

Tags: android, parse-platform, back4app

I added a Boolean to the `_User` table to identify the user as admin.

How to check it when logging in using `parse` methods like `ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password)` ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by ‘check’? - do you want to use the Boolean to validate whether the user can log in or not?

Comment: The boolean to check if the user admin or not

Comment: Can't you just access the values in the `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` object?

Comment: I want to check before logging in, so non admin users can't log in.

Comment: I understand, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To make custom validations etc before a user is logged in you can use the `beforeLogin` Cloud Code trigger which is brand new in Parse Server version 3.3.0.

See the example below and have a look at the [beforeLogin section in the Cloud Code guide](https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#beforelogin-trigger) for more details...

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeLogin(async request => {
  const { object: user }  = request;
  if(user.get('isAdmin') == false) {
   throw new Error('Access denied, you are not an admin.')
  }
});
```

**To be clear**: this is only available in Parse Server v3.3.0 and above (currently this version is not available on Back4App or Sashido).

Comment: I have to use cloud code in your case right? is there any other way?

Comment: Yep this method requires cloud code, you could check the Boolean value before login on the client side but this would be insecure so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I didn't use the cloud code function before so is there an easier way?

Comment: Using cloud code really isn’t that difficult and it’s totally worth learning how to as you can’t really build a secure app without server side code.

Comment: Can you recommend a tutorial ?

Comment: Are you self-hosting your Parse Server or using Sashido/Back4App etc?

Comment: Am using Back4app

Comment: I would suggest looking at the Back4App guides as they will show you how to deploy Cloud Code to their infrastructure - see [this getting started guide](https://www.back4app.com/docs/platform/get-started/cloud-functions) and use the [Cloud Code Guide](https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/) for more details. However, at the moment Back4App do not offer v3.3.0 of Parse Server so the `beforeLogin` trigger won't be available to you.

Comment: So I can't use your answer then

Comment: Not currently on Back4App but with a self-hosted Parse Server you can. If you would like to use the `beforeLogin` trigger on Back4App the best you can do is nag them to provide v3.3.0 on their infrastructure.

Comment: Let's [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193650/discussion-between-tom-fox-and-zacktamondo).